# Vending Machine

Tags: code-golf

## The Task

Build a function that takes a string of coins ending with an item index, and generates change as a string of coins using the least amount of coins possible.

The following are the items that can be bought (0-indexed):

`[0.45, 0.60, 0.75, 0.95, 1.10, 1.25, 1.40, 1.50, 1.75, 2.00]`

The following are the coins that can be used, with their abbreviations:

```
n = 0.05
d = 0.10
q = 0.25
D = 1.00
```

If an invalid item is selected, or the coins supplied are not enough to purchase the item, all $ is returned in the least number of coins possible.

If exact change is given, an empty string should be returned

## Test Cases

```
Dq4 = dn
qqqq4 = D
qqddddd10 = D
qqn0 = d
Dddd5 = n
qq0 = n
DD3 = Dn
Dd4 = 
DDnn9 = d
```

Assume that input will only contain valid coin characters and will always terminate in an integer.

This is my first posted question, so be please be gentle when telling me how I screwed up asking it. :)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/647/work-out-change)

Comment: Is that a bad thing? I tried to come up with something new and pulled this from some c++ homework I did a few years ago.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, in the future you should submit your questions to our [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for feedback before posting your question.  That way you don't have to worry about people "being gentle" on your first post

Comment: You need to clarify the inputs here. Are there three inputs (map of coin values, list of item prices, string of coins)?

Comment: Understood on both counts, I will post to sandbox and attempt to link related questions for future posts.

Comment: yes, those are always the item prices, and the input is a single string which contains both the coins and item

Comment: Looks good to me, thank you for helping with clarification

Comment: for exact change given, an empty string should be returned

Comment: Since you have exactly 10 options, it will help potential programs if the last digit is always an integer, and it is the only digit that is an integer, i.e., `qqddddd10` wouldn't be valid input. That way there's no typechecking involved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I said the same thing to my teacher at the time and he told me that was just part of the lesson. My solution for it was to immediately check if the string contained more than one digit and then just return the $

Comment: May we assume the integers will always be non-negative (I don't remember seeing negative keys on vending machines)?

Comment: yes, all terminating integers will be positive

Answer (score 2):

#### Python 3 - <strike>219</strike> 213 Bytes

Fixed whitespace...

So this is awful as of right now....

```
def x(s):
 v={'n':.05,'d':.1,'q':.25,'D':1}
 r=sum([v[c]for c in s[:-1]])-[.45,.6,.75,.95,1.1,1.25,1.4,1.5,1.75,2.0][int(s[-1])]
 o=''
 for x in'Dqdn':
    r=round(r, 2)
    while v[x]<=r:
     r-=v[x]
     o+=x
 return o
```

I'll go back to see if I can't get it golfed down at all...

Comment: Watch your whitespace. You can use tabs (although they don't show up in PPCG) and spaces alternatively also. IE, for the first level, one space. For the second level, one tab. For the third level, a tab and a space. Right now you have 5 (!) spaces for your third level.

Comment: I've never figured out how to get that to work right in tio xD

Comment: In regards to your comments about the test cases, `If an invalid item is selected, or the coins supplied are not enough to purchase the item, all $ is returned in the least number of coins possible.`

Comment: I guess I should read more carefully

Comment: @StephenS Since this is Python 3, they _can't_ mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: @L3viathan Oh, shows my lack of Python knowledge. Thanks. They can cut down the number of spaces though, correct?

Comment: @StephenS Sure, one space per indentation is enough.

Comment: You can also define `v` outside the function to save one byte.

Comment: @carusocomputing The prices aren't increasing by a constant .15

Comment: @PunPun1000 you're right, I think `range(.45,1.4,.15)+range(1.5,2,.25)` will help, though I know little about Python.

Comment: Your code is not working for two of the test cases, [TIO](https://tio.run/##ZU7LbsMgELzzFXsDVIyMY7eKU27@C8QpOIqlFmL8CFXVb3eXSw90JTS7w8zsPr7We/Cn43DjDRJbeE9g19/U017WnaAOUQk6IzQ4DrRXPwSiXrZPZnZztbcQ4QqTh8X0lbKWV0a2nZCvQr4hnDuhMEBlt5Itvoz408jamsmvbDFo45ZA0JQSyHkJ8@gwOzyCAC6LYfOORQENx/l5nz5G2E2y7zpmAcRK5zG34UUnvG9ct@ghHI@YVySGaS3l/EL@iBnrH@VyqbqkfcEMqOpKUakZTqWpLRXenzN1/AI)

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>281</s> 271 bytes

-10 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

```java
p->{int d[]={9,12,15,19,22,25,28,30,35,40},v[]={20,5,2,1},s=0,t;String m="Dqdn",n="";for(char c:p.toCharArray())s+=(t=m.indexOf(c))<0?0:v[t];t=p.charAt(p.length()-1)-48;s-=p.matches(".*\\d\\d")|s<d[t]?0:d[t];for(t=0;s>0;)if(s>=v[t++]){n+=m.charAt(--t);s-=v[t];}return n;}
```

Lambda that takes and returns a String

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNb@IwEIbP8CusnOzFsZwAUqkxVVWuqx6qPVEO3nxA2GTi2hO0iM1vp07pfTOyNKOZd55X45M5m7i1BZzyPzfb/a6rjGS18Z78NBVcp5PvnkeDIZ3bKidNmNA3dBUcdnti3MGzIJycAkp0WNWi7CDDqgXxC4y7vNrCGWzd@r6yISXR5GbjzbUCJPlur68rnqQ8WfJkxdOUp0uePvC55PMlX8ienwdJKnlo86TnXkuO6g4jjY62HzlEHHQUqbJ1NDsaR7JHK7B9CeWzc@ZCGfMzTVE3ooK8@Pta0oyxtXySj@cd7hVqK4a9Z6RW1AUc8EhZnLB48aB8HIaNwexYeBqJH@/veXgR@@fXedgNiCF9WaOWym@kYlVJ/UYH9Gy2Z1eYBd9vfBwjG5Bftr0rsHNAQPW3yURNwye@XTwWjWg7FDYciDXQUhhr6wsNhy4ixtR/VB8hxunyIRI5SgtjZNvAW47CjaJt56M8F6NYAKu7rp/2t08)

Ungolfed:

```java
p->{
    int d[]={9,12,15,19,22,25,28,30,35,40},
        v[]={20,5,2,1},
        s=0,
        t;

    String m="Dqdn",
           n="";

    for(char c:p.toCharArray())
        s+= (t=m.indexOf(c))<0 ? 0 : v[t];

    t=p.charAt(p.length()-1)-48;
    s-= p.matches(".*\\d\\d") | s<d[t] ? 0 : d[t];
    for(t=0;s>0;)
        if(s>=v[t++]){
            n+=m.charAt(--t);
            s-=v[t];
        }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Nice catch

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>192</s> 176 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan*

```python
s=input()
v=0
while s[0]in'qndD':v+=[1,2,20,5][ord(s[0])%11];s=s[1:]
x=int(s)
v-=x<10and x<=v and[9,12,15,19,21,25,28,30,35,40][x]
print v/20*'D'+v%20/5*'q'+v%5/2*'d'+v%5%2*'n'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxLCoMwFIXhuatwItfHLSbXBqo1M3cRMiikoFDiIza1q09jZx8czr9893G2FIKTk13ee14kXrLkM06vZ@oU05OF1ZoBOl9JxZGQGAqt5s3k51xknOu7k07xTidHjOy5i42LPHrOHtakRy99GqFa5IRcIG@RYkgg3bBh2Ai8Mq0OnSxbfKe@JlbCAJXPiNWihPWkqKkE81cWZSEEGIbV2BZ@)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think your golfed program's outputs are off for a few test cases (`Dq4`, `qqqq4`, `Dd4`).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 258 Bytes

```
$i=array(45,60,75,95,110,125,140,150,175,200);$c=array(D=>100,q=>25,d=>10,n=>5);$a=str_split($argv[1]);$p=$i[array_pop($a)];foreach($a as $x){$t+=$c[$x];$p=$c[$x]?$p:0;}$p=$t<$p?0:$p;while($t>$p){foreach($c as $n=>$x){if($t-$p>=$x){$t-=$x;echo $n;break;}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
$i=array(45,60,75,95,110,125,140,150,175,200);
$c=array(D=>100,q=>25,d=>10,n=>5);
$a=str_split($argv[1]);
$p=$i[array_pop($a)];
foreach($a as $x){
  $t+=$c[$x];
  $p=$c[$x]?$p:0;
}
$p=$t<$p?0:$p;
while($t>$p){
  foreach($c as $n=>$x){
    if($t-$p>=$x){
      $t-=$x;
      echo $n;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your coin array declaration is missing quotes and $t needs to be defined before you can add to it

$c=array('D'=>100,'q'=>25,'d'=>10,'n'=>5);

$t=0;

Once I added those I was able to run and get some good results, but qqddddd10 failed

Comment: It worked for me, but maybe there's differences in PHP versions (I'm using  5.3.29). I seem to be able to get away with not initializing variables, and it just acts like it was 0 to begin with. Maybe there's error notifications not showing because of my PHP configuration?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>230</s> 219 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to @JonathanAllan's idea of dividing all values by 5.*
*-1 byte by moving `b="Dqdn"` into the empty `s.pop()` function call.*

```js
s=>(a=[20,5,2,1],s=s.match(/\D|\d+/g),i=[9,12,15,19,22,25,28,30,35,40][s.pop(b="Dqdn")]||0,p=s.map(c=>a[b.search(c)]).reduce((y,z)=>y+z,0),(c=p-i)<0&&(c=p),a.map(v=>(x=c/v|0,c-=x*v,x)).map((v,j)=>b[j].repeat(v)).join``)
```

### Ungolfed

```js
input => {
    values = [20,5,2,1];
    coins = "Dqdn";
    input = input.match(/\D|\d+/g);
    item = [9,12,15,19,22,25,28,30,35,40][input.pop()] || 0;
    payment = input.map(c => values[coins.search(c)]).reduce((y,z) => y+z, 0);
    change = payment - item;
    if (change < 0) change = payment;
    return values.map(val => {
        count = change/val | 0;
        change -= count * val;
        return count;
    }).map((count,j) => coins[j].repeat(count))
    .join``
}
```

### Test Snippet

```js
f=
s=>(a=[20,5,2,1],s=s.match(/\D|\d+/g),i=[9,12,15,19,22,25,28,30,35,40][s.pop(b="Dqdn")]||0,p=s.map(c=>a[b.search(c)]).reduce((y,z)=>y+z,0),(c=p-i)<0&&(c=p),a.map(v=>(x=c/v|0,c-=x*v,x)).map((v,j)=>b[j].repeat(v)).join``)
```

```html
Input<br><input oninput="O.value=/\D+\d+/.test(I.value)?f(I.value)||`<empty>`:``" id="I"><br>Result<br><input id="O" disabled>
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Good thinking, that did indeed save 10 bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### C++, <s>375</s> <s>371</s> 370 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
std::map<int,int>c={{'n',1},{'d',2},{'q',5},{68,20}};void v(std::string&e){int m=0,i=0,h=0;for(;i<e.size();++i)h+=e[i]>47&&e[i]<58;m=i=0;for(;i<e.size()-1;++i)m+=c[e[i]];if(h==1){i=std::vector<int>{9,12,15,19,22,25,28,30,35,40}[e[e.size()-1]-48];m-=(m>=i)*i;}e="";for(auto&g:{68,113,100,110})while(m>=c[g]){m-=c[g];e+=g;}}
```

Comment: `h+=(e[i]>47&&e[i]<58)` can be `h+=e[i]>47&&e[i]<58`, since `&&` has higher priority than assignment/modified assignment. `m=(i=0)` can be `m=i=0` since assignment's associativity is right-to-left, and I also think that can be moved into the for-loop that follows it. And also, can the `'D'` become `68`?

Comment: I'm assuming replacing `'D'` with `68` didn't work?

Comment: @Zacharý Replacing `'D'` alone with `68` does not work, because of the `auto` keyword usage, if you have 2 different types ( even implicitly cast-able, like `int` and `short` ), the compiler can't guess what type you want and will return an error. It's the same rules as c++ template type argument declaration, where all types must match exactly. I switched all list from char to int

Comment: [264 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY9Ra4MwEIDf@yskhWraZKi1ozOeffFfOB9KzNKDGWu1ZSj@9i4KY3uaB@G4y3ffcfJ65VrK5xqN/LyXKsG67W7qXKW/rZvS6itdtV0Zx9X5mqDpmH2phGFwjcuCkQ1u6bJwyo3LDja/Hlnoj6N41Fg6D2@etWI0eqPoYKedCnyGoF5a7JVH2cWWPURMi4/65gnkXFQ7kLnKsSjoZQfYlqix86YGFReA4IRAnPVmy/39IT4Ri/7YeFDw6FjwcM8qDl6VAtItxv7sVkCI6K2fTpUGYsomI3lfCMvJXBdC7UBTOzgX47M6o/HosPpzhNOKVQskayIi7HVUzH@yvndJ0iaJ@27cGWhsLCLlFIG/hJkFIrOWw5JkyZHtl5ZESwZj3v5Bxuc3 "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>68</s>  64 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Vị“€ÐŒæı÷œ#(µ‘
ḟ®µL⁼1ȧÇ
“Þ¦£‘ɓ“Dqdn”©iÐ€ị⁹;1,0¤S¹_<?⁸Ç¤;%\:⁹®żŒṙ
```

A monadic link taking and returning lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/s4e7uRw1zHjWtOTzh6KTDy45sPLz96GRljUNbHzXM4Hq4Y/6hdYe2@jxq3GN4Yvnhdi6g0sPzDi07tBgoe3IykOdSmJL3qGHuoZWZhycADQGZ1rjT2lDH4NCS4EM7423sHzXuONx@aIm1aowVUObQuqN7jk56uHPm////CwvzDAA)** or see the [test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/s4e7uRw1zHjWtOTzh6KTDy45sPLz96GRljUNbHzXM4Hq4Y/6hdYe2@jxq3GN4Yvnhdi6g0sPzDi07tBgoe3IykOdSmJL3qGHuoZWZhycADQGZ1rjT2lDH4NCS4EM7423sHzXuONx@aIm1aowVUObQuqN7jk56uHPm/6N7DrcDNbj//x@t5FJooqSjVAgEEDoFBAwNwOw8EOUC5JuCuWCeizFYzATMzsuzVIoFAA).

#### How?

```
Vị“€ÐŒæı÷œ#(µ‘ - Link 1, item price / 5: list of digit characters, d  e.g."4"   or "10"
V              - evaluate d as Jelly code                                  4        10
  “€ÐŒæı÷œ#(µ‘ - code page indexes = [12,15,19,22,25,28,30,40,9]
 ị             - index into (1-indexed and modular)                       22        12

ḟ®µL⁼1ȧÇ - Link 2, item price / 5: list of characters, s              e.g."Dq4" or "Dq10"
 ®       - recall register value = "Dqdn" (see Main)
ḟ        - filter discard from s                                          "4"      "10"
  µ      - monadic chain separation, call that d
   L⁼1   - length equals 1?                                                1         0
       Ç - call last link as a monad                                      22        12
      ȧ  - logical and                                                    22         0

“Þ¦£‘ɓ“Dqdn”©iÐ€ị⁹;1,0¤S¹_<?⁸Ç¤;%\:⁹®żŒṙ - Main link: list of chars, s    e.g."Dqqqq4"
“Þ¦£‘                                    - code page indexes = [20,5,2]
     ɓ                                   - dyadic chain separation, left=s right=that
      “Dqdn”                             - literal = "Dqdn"
            ©                            - copy to register and yield
              Ð€                         - map across c in s:
             i                           -   1st index (0 if not found)  [1,2,2,2,2,0]
                      ¤                  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                 ⁹                       -   chain's right argument = [20,5,2]
                   1,0                   -   1 pair 0 = [1,0]
                  ;                      -   concatenate = [20,5,2,1,0]
                ị                        - index into (1-indexed)       [20,5,5,5,5,0]
                       S                 - sum                                    40
                              ¤          - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                            ⁸            -   chain's left argument = s
                             Ç           -   call last link as a monad(s)         22
                           ?             - if:
                          <              -          less than (coins not enough?)  0
                        ¹                - ...then: identity (do nothing, would be 40)
                         _               - ...else: subtract                      18
                               ;         - concatenate with right          [18,20,5,2]
                                 \       - cumulative reduce by
                                %        -   modulo                        [18,18,3,1]
                                   ⁹     -   chain's right argument = [20,5,2]
                                  :      - integer division                [ 0, 3,1,1]
                                    ®    - recall register value = "Dqdn"
                                     ż   - zip       [['D',0],['q',3],['d',1],['n',1]]
                                      Œṙ - run-length decode                   "qqqdn"
```

Comment: this is the largest Jelly program I've ever seen, by a significant margin

Comment: @Mayube Prospective meme re-tag: "longest Jelly". [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="longest+jelly"+site%3Acodegolf.stackexchange.com) (this submission actually does have less in the way of bytes used for compressed data than many I believe).