# Exact change in fewest bills and coins

Tags: code-golf, math

### Overview

In the US, the common denominations are the penny ($0.01), the nickel ($0.05), the dime ($0.10), the quarter ($0.25), one dollar, two dollars (less common but lets pretend it's common), five dollars, ten dollars, twenty dollars, fifty dollars, and one hundred dollars. ($1 to $100 respectively).

Your goal is to take an arbitrary money value and output a list of the fewest bills and coins that add up to that amount.

### Rules

- The output must be minimal. You cannot output "4175 pennies" for $41.75.
- The inputs and outputs can be any format or type, as long as you can explain what it means.
- Values must be kept the same. For instance, your program cannot accept "6523" for $65.23. It must accept the decimal value "65.23"

### Examples

If the input is $185.24, the output should be something like
$100 + $50 + $20 + $10 + $5 + $0.10 + $0.10 + $0.01 + $0.01 + $0.01 + $0.01

For the input $44.75, another acceptable output would be
[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]
Meaning 2 $20s, 2 $2s, 3 quarters, and 0 of the other denominations.

### Bonus

Accept another argument for the list of denominations so your program will work in other countries.

For example, if it's given this list of denominations.
[15, 7, 2.5, 1, 0.88, 0.2, 0.01]
and the money value "37.6", it should return something like
15 + 15 + 7 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2

Comment: I thought this was a dupe, but I can't find it. The closest ones are [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/96863/42545) and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/119600/42545), and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/647/42545), and [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/125649/42545)....

Comment: Actually, I think it is a dupe of [the third one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/647/42545). That challenge is very old, however, so it may not be worth closing this one... I'll let other users decide because my dupe vote is binding.

Comment: No 20 dollar bill?

Comment: @xnor Forgot that, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @ETHproductions When I saw that when writing this, I thought it was a similar but not duplicate challenge. It pretty much is a duplicate. It is very old like you said, though. I'd be up for closing this challenge if it's deemed appropriate.

Comment: Also close to [mixed base conversion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37905/20260), converting from base 10.

Comment: Golfers, make sure that `0.99` gives 4 pennies, since floating point errors might make it 3.

Comment: Looks like it's a dupe down to the fact that it has a bonus with unclear effects on the win and validity conditions, together with a win condition that's just implied by the tag rather than stated in the question. I'd be willing to vote to close this due to the inclarity in the win condition, in addition to the fact that it's a duplicate.

Comment: Does the input contain the dollar sign?

Comment: @ericw31415 It does not have to. `The inputs and outputs can be any format or type`

Comment: ... The question got closed as a duplicate and now I can't post an answer.

Comment: @ericw31415 Since the other one is a literal duplicate, you can post your answer there

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 54 bytes

```
#~NumberDecompose~{100,50,20,10,5,2,1,.25,.1,.05,.01}&
```

input

> [44.75]

output

> {0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0.}

## Mathematica, 82 bytes --WITH BONUS--

```
(s=#~NumberDecompose~#2;Row@Flatten@Table[Table[#2[[i]]"+",s[[i]]],{i,Length@s}])&
```

**Input**

> [37.6, {15, 7, 2.5, 1, 0.88, 0.2, 0.01}]

**output**

> 15 +15 +7 +0.2 +0.2 +0.2 +

Comment: Should have known Mathematica would have a built-in for this. Awesome.

Comment: What changed to make you need to add 2 bytes?

Comment: wrong count. this is the correct number

Answer (score 1):

## **Python 2**, <s>53</s> <s>94</s> <s>90</s> 78 bytes with bonus

```
def f(m,d=[100,50,20,10,5,2,1,.25,.1,.05,.01]):
 for i in d:
    print m//i
    m%=i
```

*The indentation is a space for line 2, and tabs for the other lines

The function takes in the amount of money and a *sorted* list of the denominations (if not US).

Examples:

```
>>> f(44.75)
0.0
0.0
2.0
0.0
0.0
2.0
0.0
3.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
>>> f(37.6, [15, 7, 2.5, 1, 0.88, 0.2, 0.01])
2.0
1.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
3.0
0.0
>>> f(8, [5,4,1])
1
0
3
```

Comment: My understanding is that the code must work for US currencies without taking it as an extra input. Also, this greedy strategy doesn't work with general currencies, like `[5,4,1]` on input 8.

Comment: Shouldn't the denominations be part of the function rather than the input?

Comment: @xnor I think you commented before my edit, I had accidentally submitted before finishing.

Comment: Edited to work with US currency without extra input.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript(ES6), 97 bytes with bonus

```
f=(m,d=[100,50,20,10,5,2,1,0.25,0.1,0.05,0.01])=>{for(i of d){z=Math.round(m/i);alert(z);m-=z*i}}
```

## Java, 209 bytes

*so verbose...*

```
interface A{static void main(String[]a){int m=Integer.valueOf(a[0]);for(double i:new Double[]{100.0,50.0,20.0,10.0,5.0,2.0,1.0,0.25,0.1,0.05,0.01}){int z = (int)Math.round(m/i);System.out.println(z);m-=z*i;}}}
```

Both use same algorithm as jacoblaw's.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! In the JS answer you can leave off the leading `0`s in the decimal numbers. Also, it would be best to post these as two separate answers (though that is no longer possible due to the question being closed).

Comment: [user75200](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/75200/user75200?tab=profile) suggested the following improvement in an edit ([which I rejected](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/suggested-edits-reject-golfing/1619#1619)): `f=m=>{for(i of(d=[100,50,20,10,5,2,1,.25,.1,.05,.01]))alert((m-=(z=Math.round(m/i)*i),z))}` Feel free to review and use it if it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 96 bytes

```php
for(;$i<11;)$argn-=$c*$r[]=$argn/($c=[100,50,20,10,5,2,1,.25,.10,.05,.01][+$i++])^0;print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYmxDoIwFAB3PoO8oZVHbQnEoTQOhsFFFzeChDQIXdrmhdm/dq6E6e5ycY2pvcY1ZjNRoJHmGGhzfmHfbnw8X/dbx3UGEy3e5HUtLk2u0ycQ0@BapTQ/VmnAnoD6wRx5ZmBNr6TERmIlUe2CFSoUVYNiLyF3SjX0BbiiGPhb6kjObyMxIK5T@vlQ2smu8x8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
x=input()+1e-5
for c in 100,50,20,10,5,2,1,.25,.1,.05,.01:print x//c;x%=c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCoAgEADAe6/YS1C06a7gYQtfI0VeVMTAXm@eZvJXnxRN782FmN@6rBtfu53uVMBDiMBEaAkNIY@gQUZlLKoBDYiPXEKs0LT2Z5ud711Eifw)

A greedy strategy works for these values. Going through currencies largest to smallest, we remove the greatest whole number of the currency, leaving the modulo as the remainder. This repeated divmod is effectively mixed based conversion.

The `+1e-5` is to ward off floating point errors where `$0.09999999999999998` is left but that's less than 1 cent.

I thought about compressing the list of values but didn't think of a good approach. There's not a uniform pattern for the values.